# Full page scroll with rotating logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, fullpage.js

I have a website which uses Fullpage.js and I need the logo to rotate 180 degrees as I scroll through each of the sections.

How can i do this

Here is the link :
http://www.bfgstudio.co.uk/testing/VIM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the `onLeave` callback or if you prefer, the `afterLoad` callback.

This way you can fire something when you are moving from one to another slide.

**jQuery:**

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    afterLoad: function (anchor, index) {
        $('#cog').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#cog {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
#cog.active {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/8/)

Answer (score 0):

there are many answer out there , you should google :

Example :

```
var $cog = $('#cog'),
$body = $(document.body),
bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $cog.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kDSqB/

```
$(function() {
  var rotation = 0, 
    scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
    rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
    var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
    $(".gear").css({
      "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
      "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
      "transform": rotationStr
    });
  });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3k6h/5/

Comment: Hey Airi, Thanks for getting back to me dude. I appreciate what you have sent me there but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. As you can see on the link I posted, when you scroll down you jump to another section. What I need is this logo to rotate 180 degrees as you scroll from one section to another. IF you click on acupuncture, for example, you'll be able to see I am already using the code you put up there. Cheers dude.

Comment: @airi If you take a look at the plugin you will see the site is not scrolling in any moment and therefore the `scroll` event won't be fired. It uses the `top`or the `translate3d` property over a wrapper.